# Erro no xamarin: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, xamarin

Estou com uma problema de inicialização do designer queria saber como resolver esse problema

> Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Imagem da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sempre cole os textos além de imagens, buscadores e crawlers não entendem fotos como texto e assim ficará difícil de outras pessoas chegarem a sua pergunta.

Comment: Fez a instalação a partir do instalador da Xamarin? Tem Java 7 x86 instalado?

Comment: Veja esta solução: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30818/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-after-updating-to-5-7

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com o Xamarin.Android, será necessário a instalação do JDK do Java. Se você já o fez e mesmo assim não funcionou, tente instalar novamente o SDK e configure o seu ambiente.

Para maiores detalhes de instalação consulte os links:
http://studyxnet.com.br/guia-de-instalacao-xamarin-parte-1/
http://studyxnet.com.br/guia-de-instalacao-xamarin-parte-2/